# Timezone offset causing wrong date

Tags: javascript, twitter-bootstrap, datepicker

I'm using Bootstrap DatePicker's `setEndDate` function ([Reference](https://bootstrap-datepicker.readthedocs.org/en/release/methods.html#setenddate)).
I need to pass to it a Javascript date object. I'm trying to convert a simple year-month-day string to a date, but depending on the windows' timezone, I get different results:

In GMT -8:

```
> new Date('2015-01-16')
  => Thu Jan 15 2015 16:00:00 GMT-0800 (Pacific Standard Time)
```

In GMT +2:

```
> new Date('2015-01-16')
  => Fri Jan 16 2015 02:00:00 GMT+0200 (Eastern Europe Standard Time)
```

So what I'm left with is a different end-date depending on what timezone the user is in, even though the server side provided the same date string.

I will appreciate help on the matter.

Comment: Both local dates are exactly the same moment in time. Do you want to convert to a given time zone?

Comment: even though they are the same moment in time, the setEndDate function interprets them differently.

Answer (score 1):

Apparently, even though the documentation states the function's argument should be a date object, it can in fact be given a string in a "m-d-yyyy" format.

So in my case all I had to do was call the function like this:

```
$('#my-input').datepicker('setEndDate', '1-16-2015');
```

Hope this helps someone.